# Is opscode chef the right solution for my task?

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra

I have a network with 10+ Windows boxes. I need to be able to automatically reconfigure them all in the certain way:

- Install Java SE Development Kit 7u79
- Set up startup script .bat on all clients (Win boxes).
- Set up script .bat to perform each 6 hours or at 03:00 every day.
- Install FF v.30-40 in folder C:/firefox/official/ff-v.X, where X is the version

I have Ubuntu 14.04 as a server: 192.168.122.100. Win boxes are 192.168.122.150-160. All required exe, msi will be located at 192.168.122.100/files/win/

The question: Is opscode chef the right solution to achieve the result or should I consider other ways?

PS: I don't have an experience as administrator and I don't have time to investigate all of the approaches myself. Currently I'm working to set up this system myself, but I still not sure if this is right investment of time in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Chef can do all of the task you've listed above.

For installing JDK 7 just use `windows_package` resource (important: remember to download cookbook `windows` from [Chef Supermarket](https://supermarket.chef.io/). It looks like this:

```
windows_package name  do
        source              src
        action              :install
        installer_type      :custom
end
```

And remember, that - on Windows systems - variable `name` should be actual name of package. You can check names in Control Panel (for example, JDK 7.79 has name `Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 79`).

Firefox can be installed in the same manner.

Setting batch scripts can be done in multiple ways - creating them with `template` resource and just execute them with another resource (`powershell_script` or `execute`). You can also implement built-in batch files as `batch` resource.

Always try to find implemented cookbook for your tasks - in *Supermarket*. If there aren't any you are looking for, you have to write your own cookbook. Since you are not asking for this, I won't write here any long tutorial, but instead will just redirect to [Chef Docs](http://docs.chef.io/).

Chef can download resources from server, so this is not a problem.

In the Internet you have also many tutorials of setting server-client Chef, but I would recommend you testing your cookbook with `chef-client` in `--local` mode first -in this mode you do not need to have any server running.

Learning Chef isn't easy nor hard - it all depends on quality of tutorial and - to be honest - many of them are just... Hard-to-understand-written. Setting environment with automatic tool is always nice idea, but you have to think if you really need this - if writting cookbook will give you many free hours in reinstalling Windows, it is for sure worth it.

Let me know if you need more informations.

Comment: Well, I am afraid, my work won't leave me sufficient time to do this for you. But still, I think that - with little help - you can do it yourself in 1-3 days (if there won't be any 'technical' problems).